# How to add a progressBar and a textView at the bottom of MapsActivity

Tags: android, textview, progress-bar, google-maps-api-2

I would like to add a progressBar and a textView at the bottom of my MapsActivity.

I tried to drag into the Design tab in `activity_maps.xml` but no widget is added. I also tried to add them using Text tab but they remain at the top-left of my activity.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.giacomo.miopgo2.MapsActivity" >

/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIndirizzo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="@+id/txtIndirizzo"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Il Mio Indirizzo"

    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pgbVitaGiocaotre"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout="@+id/linearLayout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtElisir"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="NElisir"

    android:visibility="visible" />
```

No clue about how to solve. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `activity_maps.xml`?

Comment: @MayurGajra yes, of course. Here you are.

Comment: I think i found the error,please see my answer.

Comment: It should be solved, thank you very much @MayurGajra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your root layout is not setup properly,Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtIndirizzo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Il Mio Indirizzo"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pgbVitaGiocaotre"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtIndirizzo"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtElisir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pgbVitaGiocaotre"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="NElisir"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```